# UI-Router Let URL Pass when not defined in a state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to use Angular UI-Router however I would need it to let any url pass through the browser (and make the browser navigate the page) which isn't defined (the url) in the `$stateProvider` or `$urlRouterProvider`.

I've searched through their documentation, API etc but cannot find reference for this, other than `$state.reload()` which i've used before..

Comment: Are the urls that you want to let pass using the hash? Also, is your app using HTML5 routing mode or a custom hash prefix?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of 1) a url that your app should handle and 2) a url that your app should not handle?

Comment: Ok for example, I want the user to go to /admin area.. but i won't define it in the router because it isn't going to be using angular.js-router.

Comment: We use nginx to handle things like this. Set up "routing rules" so that incoming requests go to the desired application. Of course you can do varying degrees of things like this w/other servers (Apache, etc.) Using a "pass through" approach means your Angular application has to run every time someone wants to access the "pass through" URL, which may not be desirable.

Comment: Yes, but when the user has angular already loaded, it doesn't let the user refresh the state..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED: See update at the bottom.**

From your comments I'm assuming the following:

- Your Angular app lives at the root of the domain `foo.com/`
- You are using HTML5 Mode so your app responds to "natural" urls like `foo.com/thing1` and `foo.com/thing2`
- You have some other app (not your main Angular app) that lives at `foo.com/admin`

Unfortunately, you can't have a url "pass through" like you want it to. :(

Your options are:

- Move your Angular app into a subdirectory like `foo.com/app`. Then your app will respond to URLs like `foo.com/app/thing1` and `foo.com/app/thing2`.

  - This is really the only choice if you want to use HTML5 routing mode to get "natural" looking urls.
- Turn off HTML5 routing mode so that your Angular app lives at `http://foo.com/#/` and responds to urls like `foo.com/#/thing1` and `foo.com/#/thing2`. Then when your user visits `foo.com/admin` the url will fall through to the server and get whatever app is served there.

*NOTE: This applies to both regular Angular routing using `$routeProvider` as well as using Angular-UI's `$stateProvider`.*

**UPDATE:**

In order to get this to work you have to get the url change to happen *outstide* of Angular. Here's one method that will work but it has quite a smell to it IMO and will likely be quite fragile and difficult to maintain.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
   .run(function($rootScope, $window){
      $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl){
        // You'll probably want to just watch the path and build the full url
        // based on your environment, but this will get you started.
        if(newUrl === 'http://127.0.0.1/admin') {
          // prevent Angular from continuing with the location change
          event.preventDefault();
          // $window is an Angular wrapper around the global ``window`` object.
          // This causes the browser to go to the new url outside of Angular
          $window.location.href = newUrl;
        }
      });
});
```

Of course for this to work your server must be setup to serve some other app at the `/admin` path. Also, when your user navigates back to your Angular app **it will lose all state as the Angular app will start up fresh again**. Plus, your user will have to navigate back to the **root** of your Angular app. If the user goes from `foo.com/` to `foo.com/thing1` to `foo.com/admin` they will need to navigate back to `foo.com/` to get back into your Angular app.

Comment: Interesting. Is this something that can be added to angular? Or is it something that has implications such as angular being permanently bound to listen to url changes

Comment: Updated answer with a new solution.

Comment: I have my server app set up to render the view which loads angular in it.. So it is fine if they go back to /thing1, they'll still get the view which loads angular and angular will know the state for url /thing1. Thanks :). This code solves it